# Close activity when clicking anywhere

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want my activity (a normal activity with a digital clock at the center of it) to close when I tap it anywhere. Is there a sort of `Activity.setOnClickListener` or a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes on an Activity you override the existing handlers, on controls you add touch listeners, and [activityinstance].finish() gracefully closes your app.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Write Code Goes Here means >> this.finish();
    return false;
}
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

use `onUserInteraction()` for finishing your activity this method called Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity. as [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) says